# Different service parameters in diffrent bundles?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have a service in bundle `A` which I am using in bundles `B` and `C`. Is there any way to pass a different value for one of the service arguments in each bundle where I am using it?

E.g. I have a user manager service working for diffrent apps and I need to make it work for diffrent app on initialization (based on constructor). This argument is diffrent in each of the bundles where I am using the app.

Comment: make a new service definition with the needed arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use symfony service configurator

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/configurators.html